# Inverse Square root of (diagonal + rank1) matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find inverse of square root of a matrix $A$ which is a sum of diagonal matrix and a symmetric rank 1 matrix.
IE find matrix $X$ such that $XX=A^{-1}$

Any suggestion how to do it efficiently?

In my application $d$ is 10-1000.

Comment: But that matrix is singular, because the sum of the components of a multinomial vector is non-random.

Comment: Good point, there's an extra regularization term that's added in practice to make it nonsingular, removed that part to avoid unnecessary detail

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use the specifics of your matrix well, but Eigendecomposition and associated algorithms to do it will do the trick. Write $A=PDP^{-1}$ then take every eigenvalue to the $-\frac 12$ power.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried first, and it's too slow for my application

Comment: Figures. Seemed worth a shot.